# Using calculation with an an aliased column in ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, alias

As we all know, the `ORDER BY` clause is processed after the `SELECT` clause, so a column alias in the `SELECT` clause can be used.

However, I find that I can’t use the aliased column in a calculation in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```sql
WITH data AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        ('apple'),
        ('banana'),
        ('cherry'),
        ('date')
    ) AS x(item)
)
SELECT item AS s
FROM data
--  ORDER BY s;         -- OK
--  ORDER BY item + ''; -- OK
ORDER BY s + '';        -- Fails
```

I know there are alternative ways of doing this particular query, and I know that this is a trivial calculation, but I’m interested in why the column alias doesn’t work when in a calculation.

I have tested in PostgreSQL, MariaDB, SQLite and Oracle, and it works as expected. SQL Server appears to be the odd one out.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can only `ORDER BY` by the exact columns which appear in the `SELECT` clause.  I'm frankly surprised that the `ORDER BY s+ ''` worked on Oracle.  But note that on Oracle, empty string is the same as `NULL` ... maybe you were really doing `ORDER BY NULL` on Oracle.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It also works in the other DBMSs above.

Comment: Lots of things work differently between different DBMSs. That's why there are different DBMSs. If they all did every little obscure thing the exact same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) clearly states that:

> The column names referenced in the ORDER BY clause must correspond to
> either a column or column alias in the select list or to a column
> defined in a table specified in the FROM clause without any
> ambiguities. **If the ORDER BY clause references a column alias from
> the select list, the column alias must be used standalone, and not as
> a part of some expression** in ORDER BY clause:

Technically speaking, your query should work since order by clause is *logically* evaluated after select clause and it should have access to all expressions declared in select clause. But without <del>looking at</del> having access to the SQL specs I cannot comment whether it is a limitation of SQL Server or the other RDBMS implementing it as a bonus feature.

Anyway, you can use `CROSS APPLY` as a trick.... it is part of `FROM` clause so the expressions should be available in all subsequent clauses:

```
SELECT item
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT item + '') AS CA(item_for_sort)
ORDER BY item_for_sort
```

Comment: Ah, that explains it. It’s just a Microsoft thing. Thanks

Comment: That’s a good trick. In my case, I would normally use a CTE and be done with it.

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware the docs spelled this behavior out, but I do find it rewarding in some way that the example they provide is `ORDER BY SchemaName + ''; -- wrong`

Answer (score 2):

It is simply due to the way expressions are evaluated. A more illustrative example:

```
;WITH data AS
(
   SELECT * FROM (VALUES('apple'),('banana')) AS sq(item)
)
SELECT item AS s
  FROM data
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN s END;
```

This returns the same `Invalid column name` error. The `CASE` expression (and the concatenation of `s + ''` in the simpler case) is evaluated before the alias in the select list is resolved.

One workaround for your simpler case is to append the empty string in the select list:

```
SELECT
  item + '' AS s
...
ORDER BY s;
```

There are more complex ways, like using a derived table or CTE:

```
;WITH data AS
(
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES('apple'),('banana') AS sq(item)
),
step2 AS
(
  SELECT item AS s FROM data
)
SELECT s FROM step2 ORDER BY s+'';
```

This is just the way that SQL Server works, and I think you could say "well SQL Server is bad because of this" but SQL Server could also say "what the heck is this use case?" :-)

Comment: “what the heck is this use case?” - One technique to sort by an arbitrary order is something like `ORDER BY charindex(colour,'red,orange,yellow,green,blue,violet')`. I know that I can put that calculation in the `SELECT` clause, but I wanted to check what the situation was regarding calculations; the `+''` was just the simplest calculation without complicating the issue. I should have thought that if `SELECT` is truly processed before `ORDER BY` then all of the aliases appear as real column names.

Comment: @Manngo The specs and folks like Celko will say ORDER BY is processed last. But database engines have gotten more complex since the textbooks were published, and there are exceptions. :-)

Comment: Not disagreeing with you there. Note that Microsoft also thinks `ORDER BY` is processed after `SELECT` in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement, particularly “Conversely, because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as the ORDER BY clause.” I suppose there is a difference between _referenced_ and _used_.

Comment: Just confirming, you’re saying that SQL Server evaluates expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause _before_ the `SELECT` clause?

Comment: In summary: if you need to run computation in the `ORDER BY` clause you need to reference **original column names/aliases** (as would be available in the `FROM` clause). This poses a big problem if you have computation in the `SELECT` clause and would like to do **further** computation on the result in the `ORDER BY`. To workaround this problem you need to nest your `SELECT` statements or use a CTE or repeat the whole computation code in `ORDER BY`. This looks like a legacy quirk/bug to me (I remember encountering it over 15 years ago in SQL 2005, if my memory serves me right).

Comment: No, usually _simple aliases_ in ORDER BY are evaluated at the end. But when you introduce _expressions_ there instead of referencing columns directly, it can force earlier evaluation.